# How to change the values repeatedly accurs in Array object

Tags: javascript

Input:-
  Here i'm having array object in which natraj is repeating so i need to append some count like given example.

```
var aa= [
     {name:'natraj'},
     {name:'ajai'},
     {name:'natraj'},
     {name:'ajai'},
     {name:'barath'},
     {name:'ajai'},
     {name:'barath'},
     {name:'natraj'},
   ]
```

output:-

```
  [
     {name:'natraj'},
     {name:'ajai'},
     {name:'natraj_1'},
     {name:'ajai_1'},
     {name:'barath'},
     {name:'ajai_2'},
     {name:'barath_1'},
     {name:'natraj_2'},
   ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep a running count:

```js
var aa = [{name:'natraj'},{name:'ajai'},{name:'natraj'},{name:'ajai'},{name:'barath'},{name:'ajai'},{name:'barath'},{name:'natraj'},]

let counts = {}
aa.forEach(o => {
  if (counts[o.name]) {
    o.name += `_${counts[o.name]++}`
  } else {
    counts[o.name] = 1
  }
});

console.log(aa)
```